# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have registered on portals.exosite and I added device with some data. I'm trying to GET this data using retrofit and sending GET request with authentication but I get an error message as in title.

My interface:

```
import java.util.List;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.http.GET;

public interface RetroInterface{

    @GET("/api/portals/v1/data-sources/0e948702d54c4b11fa449cbd9c9a197ba0c664b6")
    public void getData(Callback<List<Data>> response);


}
```

class Data for getting data and units:

```
public class Data {

    private String data;
    private String unit;

    public String getFetchedData(){  return data;}

    public void putData(String data){ this.data = data; }

    public String getFetchedUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}
```

and the request:

```
public static final String ENDPOINT =
            "https://portals.exosite.com";

    List<Data> dataList;


    private void requestData(){

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String username = "my_email";
        String password = "my_password";

        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new  RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
                .setClient(new OkClient(client));

        final String credentials = username + ":" + password;
        builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                String string = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(
                        credentials.getBytes(),
                        Base64.NO_WRAP
                );
                request.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
                request.addHeader("Authorization", string);
            }
        });

        RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();


        RetroInterface api = adapter.create(RetroInterface.class);

        api.getData(new Callback<List<Data>>(){

            @Override
            public void success(List<Data> arg0, Response arg1){

                dataList = arg0;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data successfully fetched ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError arg0){

                String erro = arg0.toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,erro,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,erro);
            }
        });
    }
```

and this shoud be given in response from exosite:

```
{"data":[[1432735517,19]],"info":{"basic":{"modified":1430694552,"subscribers":0,"type":"dataport"},"description":{"format":"float","meta":"{\"datasource\":{\"description\":\"\",\"unit\":\"C\"}}","name":"Temperature","preprocess":[],"public":false,"retention":{"count":"infinity","duration":"infinity"},"subscribe":null},"shares":[],"storage":{"count":4,"first":1430694960,"last":1432735517,"size":48},"subscribers":[],"tags":[]},"rid":"0e948702d54c4b11fa449cbd9c9a197ba0c664b6","unit":"C"}
```

and I want to get from this response "data" and "unit". I am new to android and I have no idea what is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

**So from what I've read, you can't use List as it's not a list but an object. Change this and it should function correctly.**

I assume it's got to do with a method somewhere that needs an array to call, but the response object that you are sending it is more of a 'dictionary' similar to a JSON object.

Comment: The solution: Data class: changing "String data" to "List<List<Long>> data;". In request and interface: changing every " <List<Data>>" to "<Data>" and in success method changing "List<Data> agr0" to "Data arg0". Now it works fine.